# Python extract data from xml and save it to excel

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, arcpy

I would like to extract some data from an XML file and save it in a table format, such as XLS or DBF.

Here is XML file i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ADD_LandIndex_001>
      <CNTROLAREA>
        <BSR>
          <VERB>ADD</VERB>
          <NOUN>LandIndex</NOUN>
          <REVISION>001</REVISION>
        </BSR>
      </CNTROLAREA>
      <DATAAREA>
        <LandIndex>
          <reportId>AMI100031</reportId>
          <requestKey>R3278458</requestKey>
          <SubmittedBy>EN4871</SubmittedBy>
          <submittedOn>2015/01/06 4:20:11 PM</submittedOn>
          <LandIndex>
            <agreementdetail>
              <agreementid>001       4860</agreementid>
              <agreementtype>NATURAL GAS</agreementtype>
              <currentstatus>
                <status>ACTIVE</status>
                <statuseffectivedate>1965/02/18</statuseffectivedate>
                <termdate>1965/02/18</termdate>
              </currentstatus>
              <designatedrepresentative>
              </designatedrepresentative>
            </agreementdetail>
          </LandIndex>
        </LandIndex>
      </DATAAREA>
    </ADD_LandIndex_001>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am interested in information inside the *agreementdetail* tag which is under DATAAREA/LandIndex/LandIndex/

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to **MattDMo** this task has moved a bit from its dead point. So I made this script below. It iterates the file and gets all instances of the *agreementdetail* and outputs *agreementid* and *agreementtype* for each.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import arcpy

xmlfile = 'D:/Working/Test/Test.xml'
element_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = element_tree.getroot()
agreement = root.findall(".//agreementdetail")
result = []
elements = ('agreementid', 'agreementtype')

for a in agreement:
    obj = {}
    for e in elements:
        obj[e] = a.find(e).text
    result.append(obj)

arcpy.AddMessage(result)
```

The output I am receiving consists of a bunch of this strings: {'agreementid': '001       4860', 'agreementtype': 'NATURAL GAS'}

Now I need to convert this output into a table format (.csv, .dbf, .xls etc.) so that agreementid and agreementtype are columns:

```
agreementid    | agreementtype 
001       4860 | NATURAL GAS
```

I will be very grateful if you could guide me on how to accomplish it. Or maybe any example?

P.S. Python version is 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import arcpy

xmlfile = 'D:/Working/Test/Test.xml'
element_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = element_tree.getroot()
agreement = root.find(".//agreementid").text
arcpy.AddMessage(agreement)
```

The `root.find()` call uses an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression (quick cheatsheet is in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)) to find the first tag at any level under the current level named `agreementid`. If there are multiple tags named that in your file, you can use `root.findall()` and iterate over the results. If, for example, there are three fields named `agreementid`, and you know you want the second one, then `root.findall(".//agreementid")[1]` should work.

Comment: Actually my goal is to get all evidences of <agreementdetail> with all embedded elements because in fact this xml contains a lot of <agreementdetail> tags, I just shortened it for this post.

Comment: @OlgaK. there are many posts on SO on how to create and write to CSV files using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, using a variety of inputs. Browse through the docs, search SO for relevant questions, and try out some code for yourself. If you're still having problems, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

MattDMo has given a sufficient answer to the problem, but I just want to remind you that python has a [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) which makes it easier to write comma separated data, which is typically then read into applications such as databases or spreadsheets.

From the docs:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```