# Transform an XML (with its XSD) to an Excel file with python

Tags: python, xml, excel

I am searching a way to transform an XML file into an Excel file using python. My XML do not contains data, just some tags (it's a template). I want to convert it to an Excel file to put some data in and then, back to the XML to use the data.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Here is the library, which you can use https://github.com/knadh/xmlutils.py

Comment: Also you should pay attention to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846942/python-extract-data-from-xml-and-save-it-to-excel

Comment: The library seems to do the job, but does it keep the constraints imposed by the xsd file ?